# How to prevent session sharing from two different Laravel projects?

Tags: php, laravel, session

I am now developing two websites based on Laravel framework. One of the websites is the cms(website a) managing data in a database and another website(website b) cannot get data from the database directly. Instead, the website gets data from the cms through an API connection. However, when website b retrieves data from the website a, the session in cms will timeout immediately which may be caused by session sharing.

How can I prevent session sharing between two websites?

Comment: Laravel uses an app key for encrypting session data, make sure your separate project has a different key. You can generate a new one with `php artisan key:generate`

Comment: @NAME You could separate sessions by using a subdomain for the cms